# How to Create a Configuration Batch file for VNC Server?

Tags: batch, vncserver, parameters, silent-install

I made a batch file for **[VNC Server](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/)** to make Windows 10 x64 automatically (Unattended). The software is properly implemented and installed silently, but unfortunately the configuration parameters of the software do not change in "Service Mode". I've used the following code:

```
VNC-Server-6.7.1-Windows-64bit.msi /qn /norestart REBOOT=ReallySuppress LICENSEKEY=*****-*****-*****-*****-***** ENABLEAUTOUPDATECHECKS=0 ENABLEANALYTICS=0 BlackListThreshold=0 BlackListTimeout=1 DisableClose=1 DisableTrayIcon=1 AuthTimeout=0 ENABLEANALYTICS=0  ADDLOCAL=FeatureServer,FeatureMirrorDriver AllowChangeDefaultPrinter=0 EnableRemotePrinting=0 ProxyServer=0
```

This section is well executed and the software is installed:

```
VNC-Server-6.7.1-Windows-64bit.msi /qn /norestart REBOOT=ReallySuppress LICENSEKEY=*****-*****-*****-*****-***** ENABLEAUTOUPDATECHECKS=0 ENABLEANALYTICS=0
```

But this part (parameters) does not change at all:

```
 BlackListThreshold=0 BlackListTimeout=1 DisableClose=1 DisableTrayIcon=1 AuthTimeout=0 ENABLEANALYTICS=0  ADDLOCAL=FeatureServer,FeatureMirrorDriver AllowChangeDefaultPrinter=0 EnableRemotePrinting=0 ProxyServer=0
```

All program Parameters are **[here](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002251297-VNC-Server-Parameter-Reference-)**
For example I have shown parts of "BlackListThreshold" and "BlackListTimeout" in picture (the default values have not changed).

[**picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRARR.png)

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: add to your question: What OS are you running VNC server on? Add OS tag. Are you running VNC Server in service mode? It is not possible to specify parameters at the command line for VNC Server in Service Mode.

Comment: yes, VNC Server are in service mode, why i cants change parameters when VNC Server are in service mode?!! I did the installation process by default.so do i need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

Your [here](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002251297-VNC-Server-Parameter-Reference-) says nothing about applying parameters during installation.

Read [Configuring VNC Connect Using Parameters](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002253878).

Parameters can be applied by modifying the Windows registry.

How to add to the windows registry from the command line:

Create regfiles:

RealVNC info for doing this incomplete. If you work on it hard enough you will figure it out but IMO you would be better off setting the parameters though the `Options > Expert dialog box` and exporting the regfiles `HKCU\Software\RealVNC\vncserver` and / or  `HKCU\Software\Policies\RealVNC\vncserver` and / or `HKLM\Software\RealVNC\vncserver` and / or  `HKLM\Software\Policies\RealVNC\vncserver` that the expert dialog box creates. You will learn faster how to create the regfiles you need and you will have them the next time you need to configure VNC Server. Export them to `vncserver1.reg`, `vncserver2.reg`, ....

Install VNC Server and update the registry:

```
VNC-Server-6.7.1-Windows-64bit.msi /qn /norestart REBOOT=ReallySuppress LICENSEKEY=*****-*****-*****-*****-***** ENABLEAUTOUPDATECHECKS=0 ENABLEANALYTICS=0
regedit /s "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\vncserver1.reg"
regedit /s "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\vncserver2.reg"
```

Comment: We always appreciate contributions to the Suggested Edit queue, **but** if you are going to correct another person's spelling, you should ensure that *your* spelling is correct, also:  it is *receiving*... https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/966217

Comment: @run5k Thank you.

Comment: That was perfect. It worked :) . With your guidance, I finally succeeded. All the desired parameters were successfully installed with the software. Thank you very much somebadhat

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply.
I forgot to write the Windows version. I have now edited it.
Thank you for your guidance. You have introduced a good method. But using this method, I will have another problem. I think the policy (reg files) should run "after" installing the software. Is this idea true at all? i don't know if i can follow the software installation steps in the Windows installation process. I first need to run a batch file containing the installation instructions in silent mode next to the software file (step A) , and then I need to install registry files 1 and 2 (step B). I don't know if I can do these two steps in order, and whether it's possible. Also, I did not find the program path in the specified path:

```
HKCU\Software\RealVNC\vncserver
```

The path i found the data was as follows:

```
HKLM\software\RealVNC\vncserver
```

IDK, but maybe because i don't have another local user. I only have local administrator user
Also, i did not find the second path in the specified path:

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\RealVNC\vncserver
```

Neither in `HKCU` path nor in `HKLM` path (i attach a Screenshot of it).

[image]

If i want this software to be installed on all of Windows users, it must be installed on the main local user (administrator)? Should the route change? like this?

```
HKLM\software\RealVNC\vncserver
```

Comment: updated my answer.   "(reg files) should run "after" installing the software." "I can do these two steps in order". I will find the program path. I will install for all users.

Comment: update your answer with your solution.